# Worksheet_Change Event giving run-time error 13 - Type Mismatch When Inserting Rows

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using Excel VBA and have a worksheet_change event like so:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target = Range("rel_type") Then
       --some code
    End If
End Sub
```

That code works great when I make a change to the named range "rel_type".  However if I insert a row anywhere else in the spreadsheet, I get run-time error 13 - type mismatch on the first line of that Sub.  Does anybody know a workaround?  I'm not that familiar with the Worksheet_Change event and can't seem to find good documentation (or at least documentation that references why this error would occur).  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    On Error GoTo Whoa

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("rel_type")) Is Nothing Then
       Application.EnableEvents = False

       '--some code
    End If

LetsContinue:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP**

> > > Yes, that's exactly what I needed! Thanks! It worked like a charm. I was not familiar with Intersect or the EnableEvents option, so I learned a lot here--I appreciate it. – rryanp 16 secs ago

**INTERSECT**: The Intersect Method will return a Range Object that represents the intersection of two, or more, ranges.

See this link

**Topic: Intersect Method [Excel 2003 VBA Language Reference]**

**Link**: [Intersect - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa195772%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

**ENABLEEVENTS**: You have to use the EnableEvents property to prevent any probable endless loops which the VBA code might initiate. When you set this property to `False`, VBA will not raise any events and the `Worksheet_Change` event will run only once. Also you should always be sure to set EnableEvents property back to `True` to enable events to be called normally the next time.

HTH

Sid

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I needed!  Thanks!  It worked like a charm.  I was not familiar with Intersect or the EnableEvents option, so I learned a lot here--I appreciate it.

Comment: @rryanp: Updated my post with more info :)